# Best practices for running worker threads for periodically updating the UI

Tags: android, multithreading

What are the best practices for running worker threads in the background that periodically update UI elements in an activity. The goal here is to avoid any screen freezing on any kind of updates and if there are any specific guidelines/standards that should be followed.

Comment: use intent service with LocalboadcastManager in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Service for Background Work.
I have made an example for you.

***Try this.***

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "TestActivity";
    public final static String RECEIVER_ACTION = "com.action.MyReceiverAction";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_work);

        registerMyReceiver();

        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));


    }


    MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    private void registerMyReceiver() {


        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVER_ACTION);

        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive() called");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

**BackgroundService.java**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {


    private String TAG = "BackgroundService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onBind() called");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand() called");

        notifyToUI();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    /**
     * This Methd will notify your Activity
     */
    private void notifyToUI()
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(TestActivity.RECEIVER_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Now at the end register BackgroundService in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<service android:name=".BackgroundService"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. This works but on Samsung devices with the default power manager, it seems to get crashed after 15 minutes or so. Is there a way to prevent the power managers from killing the background service?

Comment: Can you please show me your crash-logs. It will be helpful to know the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) (or some other timer) to periodically start a service. That service then updates the model, and notifies UI thread with for example [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). UI thread can then use BroadcastReceiver to catch the Intent and update itself.